# List installed RPM and install RPM from OpenShift cartridge

Tags: openshift-online-2

Is there a way to list installed RPM from OpenShift SSH console and install RPM from OpenShift cartridge?

`yum list` doesn't work:

```
error: cannot open Packages database in /var/lib/rpm
CRITICAL:yum.main:

Error: rpmdb open failed
```